# Chrome extension to use print style

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In Chrome 49 you can preview the print style by:

1. Open developer toolbar
2. Click the "..." icon
3. Go to "More tools" > "Rendering settings"
4. Click "Emulate print media"

Too many steps as I toggle it back and forth multiple times per day.  I couldn't find an existing extension, so hoped to make one but haven't had any success.

Any one know how I can do this?

Note: The pages I am testing have one css file, which includes both "normal" screen rules, and "@media print" rules.

Comment: Try checking whether this setting is available through the remote debugging protocol, see [`chrome.debugger`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger).

Answer (score 1):

There is no function in the Google Chrome Extension to do what you want. So making an extension will not resolve your problem...

You should look for software doing macro for you like Automator on Mac.